# Looping through a map in helm

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I am new to yaml and helm templating and have a question in it.

I have the following in my values.yaml file

```
regionInfo:
   usa:
      DrRegions: uk
      region: usa                
      region_key: usa
   uk:
     DrRegions: usa
     region: uk
     region_key: lhr
```

I need to iterate over the above map and the output should be in this format  for each region

```
{{ $region }}:
    dnsAbbrev: {{ region_key }}
    abbrev: {{ region_key }}
    drRegion: {{ DrRegions }}
```

I tried the following
**Method 1**

```
{{ range $reg, $props := .Values.regionInfo }}
                
{{ $reg }}:
dnsAbbrev: {{ $props.region_key }}
abbrev: {{ $props.region_key }}
drRegion: {{ $props.DrRegions }}
{{ end }}
```

**Method 2**

```
{{ range reg, props := .Values.regionInfo }}
{{ range $props }}
                
{{ $reg }}:
dnsAbbrev: {{ .region_key }}
abbrev: {{ .region_key }}
drRegion: {{ .DrRegions }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

I was getting couldn't range over map in both the scenarios... Any help or guidance on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: The first option looks correct to me (except that the property keys need to be indented).  What output do you get?  What's going wrong?

Comment: When helm template runs i see the following error - range can't iterate over map[usa:map[DrRegions:uk region:usa region_key:usa] uk:map[DrRegions:usa region:uk region_key:lhr]]